# iOS7: MKAnnotation centerOffset?

Tags: ios, dictionary, ios7, mkannotation

So the centerOffset property of MKAnnotation does not seem to work on iOS7 for working with custom annotation images...
Below are images taken in iOS6 (working) and in iOS7 (not working).

Do you guys know what's causing this issue? Is there any fix for this?

It's not that the centerOffset value is incorrent in iOS7, it's that the offset does not change whatever it receives as a value.

[image: iOS6]
[image: iOS7]

**EDIT**: Sample code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MapAnnotation *ann = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithName:@"Some annotation" latitude:46.910068 longitude:17.881984 tag:1 type:MAP_ANNOTATION_TYPE_REQUEST];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:ann];

    MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(46.910068, 17.881984) radius:10];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:circle];

}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKCircle class]]) {

        MKCircleView *cv = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:overlay];
        cv.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:247/255.f green:85/255.f blue:86/255.f alpha:0.2];
        cv.lineWidth = 1;
        cv.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:247/255.f green:85/255.f blue:86/255.f alpha:1.0];
        return cv;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    //User location
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    //Annotations
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;
    if(annotation != self.mapView.userLocation)
    {
        // Dequeue the pin
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"myPin";
        pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinAnnotation == nil )
            pinAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        pinAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"subscription-map-icon"];
        pinAnnotation.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -20);
    }

    return pinAnnotation;
}
```

`MapAnnotation` is a simple annotation class that has a few irrelevant properties.

Comment: I am not able to duplicate this problem (centerOffset seems to be fine in iOS 7).  If you'd like, please update the question with the code that wasn't working.  In viewForAnnotation, were you perhaps creating an _MKPinAnnotationView_ and setting its image (instead of creating a plain _MKAnnotationView_ which is the correct thing to do)?  MKPinAnnotationView should only be used for the standard pins and you should not be setting their image.

Comment: I get this error event when starting a project from scratch and implementing a barebones viewForAnnotation. I updated my question above.

Comment: As I said, in viewForAnnotation, create a plain **MKAnnotationView** when using your own image.  Do not create an **MKPinAnnotationView**.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I have not read your comment to the end. Thank you!

Comment: Had the same problem and solved with your answer. Thanks @ZoltánMatók.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**EDIT:**

As @Anna Karenina made me realize, **I was using MKPinAnnotationView instead of MKAnnotationView**. Apparently MKPinAnnotation has a baked in centerOffset, that is the reason behind the strange behaviour.

**THE ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

For anyone having the same issue, this seems to be a bug in iOS7.

Workaround:

Subclass `MKAnnotationView` and overwrite the `setter method` for the `centerOffset` property.

Nothing new in the .h header file, and this is how the .m implementation file should look like:

```
#import "MyAnnotationView.h"

@implementation MyAnnotationView
@synthesize centerOffset = _centerOffset;

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setCenterOffset:(CGPoint)centerOffset {
    _centerOffset = centerOffset;
}

@end
```

**Don't miss the `@synthesize` part on the top!**

Comment: Original answer was the only way I got an MKAnnotationView to move in ios7.

Comment: I'd upvote this twice if I could.  Switched from using MKPinAnnotationView to MKAnnotationView and missed changing it in once place.

Comment: Same thing here :P I was using "MKPinAnnotationView" "MKAnnotationView"

FACEPALM!

Comment: Yeah. The exact mistake in my code is 

    MKAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotation"];

Thanks for your solution.